How to bulk enable shared address for contacts
In my install I have teachers (individuals) and Schools (Organisation>>sub-type 'School'). We do not record any address details for the teachers but now we'd like to enable the 'shared address' option for our teachers so that they have address fields showing in their contact summary page for the school that they work for. I can easily do this one at a time as it's just a case of ticking a box in the contact summary 'use another contact's address' and then selecting the employer school but this isn't practical for all of them. Is there a way which I can in effect check that box and have the correct employer school selected for all my teachers?
Thanks
CiviCRM 5.51.3
Drupal

A couple of options.
Make a SearchKit based on Addresses and it gives you access to the Master Address ID field which you may then be able to use to 'edit in line' or use 'update entity' to bulk update based on an existing Relationship (which you could presumably add to the SK once you add the Contact's Entity
Alternatively you might be able to do this by doing an export and using the https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-csv-import-gui extension

Will be good for others if you can report back with your own Answer if you sort something out.
